i want it to show a modalbottom sheet when the add persistentnavbarItem is clicked
PersistentBottomNavBarItem(
        onPressed: _openRatingsLayer,

        icon: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 35,
        ),
        title: ("Add"),
        activeColorPrimary: Colors.orange.shade800,
        inactiveColorPrimary: Colors.grey,
      ),

void _openRatingsLayer() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      isDismissible: true,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      context: context,
      builder: (ctx) {
        return Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(ctx).viewInsets.bottom),
          child: const DummyScreen(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

I'm expecting that when i click on the add navbar item, it shows me modalbottomsheet and not take me to a new screen... that's why i tried to use the onPressed function of the persistentNavBarItem but it gave an error

what error are you getting?

OnPressed parameter is function with one argument of BuildContext? type =>  Function(BuildContext?)
Your function doesn't have this parameter => _openRatingsLayer() so you can't assign it the way you assigned it, because you are passing function of wrong type.
You can modify your function and implement BuildContext? argument => _openRatingsLayer(BuildContext? context), but I assume you want to use context of the whole screen and not the context of the navigation bar. In that case is better to add function like this:
onPressed: (navBarContext) => _openRatingsLayer(),

or
onPressed: (navBarContext) {_openRatingsLayer();},

But don't forget to call navigation bar controller to navigate to different screen after closing the modal.
See custom-navigation-bar-styling
